# Laravel display image in email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am sending an email to my users of something they've submitted to confirm.
The users can upload images so I want to display these images in the email overview.

The images are being saved and I save the path in my database. Only when I try to display the images I get `src=(unknown)` when I spectate in my email client.

This is how I print out the images:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo '/storage/' . $filename ?>" />
```

$filename is passed as data from my mailable class when I just echo the $filename it is the right data from my database so there is no issue there.

Comment: You need to give the absolute URL like http://example.com/storage/image.png

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @codeit repsonse I fixed it this way:

```
<img class="mini-thumbnail thumbnail" src="<?php echo url('/storage/' . $filename); ?>" />
```

Comment: but there is a drawback of using url(), i.e. if ever your set the email process in the scheduler then the url() function doesn't work there.

Comment: There is no need to put this email process in the scheduler since it's a confirmation email of something the user has submitted. Thanks tho! :)

Answer (score 0):

In email you can not simply show the image from storage folder until you give the absolute url of your website.

i.e. it should be like this:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php $SITE_URL.'/storage/' . $filename ?>" />
```

where `$SITE_URL` should have the absolute path of your website like: `www.google.com/`

That's it.

Comment: If you don't want to send the emails with absolute URLs, you can send the images with Base64 encoding.